# DomPDF - Cached_PDF_Decorator declaration error

Tags: php, interface, implementation, dompdf, construct

Fatal error: Declaration of Cached_PDF_Decorator::_*construct() must be compatible with that of Canvas::*_construct() in /my/path/to/cached_pdf_decorator.cls.php on line 22

relevant code in Cached_PDF_Decorator:

```
class Cached_PDF_Decorator extends CPDF_Adapter implements Canvas {
...
function __construct($cache_id, CPDF_Adapter $pdf) {
  $this->_pdf = $pdf;
  $this->_cache_id = $cache_id;
  $this->_fonts = array();

  $this->_current_page_id = $this->_pdf->open_object();
}
```

relevant code in interface Canvas:

```
interface Canvas {
function __construct($paper = "letter", $orientation = "portrait", DOMPDF $dompdf);
```

Shouldn't the parameters in Cached_PDF_Decorator's __construct match up with those in Canvas?
Thanks!

Comment: Why yes, they should.  They have to, according to the interface.  This is surely a bug that you should report upstream.

Comment: And, indeed, the [code has been updated](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/commit/dfb7104a12dc703c10b25d9146bd19b6f6f49a5b). If you have not yet done so, update your copy of dompdf to resolve the issue.